# Are iCloud images being cached in iOS device after being retrieved by application?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, icloud

I have a simple UITableView, where each cell has an thumbnail picture that the user may have taken with its iOS device camera.

If iCloud is enabled the image is saved in it. However I was wondering if some sort of caching happens when loading the image, because I have notice a slowness on first loading then, even if the piece of code is called  again when cell display on screen, the image show quite fast.

This is the relevant code fragment, I have omitted the logic for building the cell, I think it is not relevant, because the question is about other aspects:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)table cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // logic for retrieve data and build cell

    NSURL *ubiquityUrl = [fm URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
    NSURL *docURL = [ubiquityUrl
                     URLByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"P_%@_%@.jpg",imgId,@"thumbnail"]
                     isDirectory:NO];
    // this a custom object extending UIDocument
    IP2DataDocument *dataDocument = [[IP2DataDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:docURL];

    [dataDocument openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
        if (success) {
            NSLog(@"iCloud document opened");
            // logic for filling table cell picture 
        } else {                
            NSLog(@"failed opening document from iCloud");                
        }


       }];

    // returning cell
}
```

I can see "iCloud document opened" in Xcode, each time the cell display. 
If some sort of caching occurs, can you point out where and how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Document-based App Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocumentBasedAppPGiOS/ManageDocumentLifeCycle/ManageDocumentLifeCycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011149-CH4-SW25) says:

> When you run a metadata query to learn about an application’s iCloud documents, the query results are placeholder items (`NSMetadataItem` objects) for document files. The items contain metadata about the file, such as its URL and its modification date. The document file is not in the iCloud container directory.
>
> The actual data for a document is not downloaded until one of the following happens:
>
> - Your application attempts to open or access the file, such as by calling `openWithCompletionHandler:`.
> - Your application calls the `NSFileManager` method `startDownloadingUbiquitousItemAtURL:error:` to download the data explicitly.

To sum it up: The first time you open your document, it may not have been downloaded from iCloud yet, which is why it'll take longer. Afterwards, there is a local copy of the file that is obviously faster to read.

Answer (score 0):

It is your docURL or specially

```
NSURL *ubiquityUrl = [fm URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
```

You don't actual access directly to iCloud.  You access an equivalent local location (ubiquityUrl) that is iCloud enabled.  If the file that you try to get has not been downloaded locally yet, then the local iCloud daemon will download it at the time you are accessing.  Once this occurs, it is stored in your device locally.  So the next time, you try to access it again using the docURL, it is much quicker because of this.  Also the iCloud daemon is responsible for syncing version your document.  So you don't need to worry about that if someone else has updated a newer version of the same document from another device.